# load() method returning null value while get() method returning value in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

i have a persistence class **Student** which having two attributes id and name.
while i am using
**Student s2=(Student)sf.getCurrentSession().get(Student.class, 1);**
i am getting the **id** and **name** value stored in the **DB**.
But while using **Student s2=(Student)sf.getCurrentSession().load(Student.class, 1);**  the **id** value is coming as **0** and **name** as **null**.
Can anybody just help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate `load()` doesn't hit the database, only gives you a proxy object.

Reference: https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/

Comment: Thanks @Akashdeep. i got it.